# How to Prevent Triplicates in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, random, dataframe

I have the following code:

```
stim_df = pd.concat([block1,block2,bloc3,block4], axis=0, ignore_index=True).sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
stim_df.columns = ["Word","Condition"] 

#Check for triplicates: 
for j in xrange(len(stim_df)):
    if j == 0 or j == 1:
        pass
    else:
        if stim_df["Condition"][j] == stim_df["Condition"][j-1] == stim_df["Condition"][j-2]:
            stim_df[j-2:j+3] = stim_df[j-2:j+3].reindex([j-2,j-1,j+2,j,j+1])
```

What I'm trying to prevent from happening is three adjacent rows with the same "Conditions" value appearing together. So if my conditions are "1","2",and "3", I want to prevent an order like 1,1,2,2,2,1,3,1 from occurring, where the condition value 2 appears three times in a row.

Here's a quick sample of a portion of the df:

```
        Condition  Word
0           1  neut
1           2   pos
2           3   neg
3           3   neg
4           3   neg
5           2   pos
6           1  neut
7           2   pos
8           2   pos
9           2   pos
10          2   pos
```

My code doesn't solve the issue. Would it be better to create a pseudo-randomization function, rather than trying to deal with this after I've already randomly mixed the dataframe? Any assistance or suggestions would really help.

Comment: what is it you're trying to achieve? if the original dataset has none of these triples you could select "blocks" from this set and shuffle the blocks so that you the "edges" are different values?

Comment: Could you also show us a small snippet of your DataFrame?

Comment: @user666 just added a sample

Comment: This question is approximately 99% related to algorithms, and about 1% related to pandas. Your tagging keep away your target audience, and your dataframe snippets merely confuse those looking at the question. The fact that your problem came up *in the context* of pandas, does not make it a pandas question, necessarily.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to generate a sequence with no repetitions, or just remove the a sequence like `2,2,2`?

If you're looking for the latter, try using `diff` to remove repeating sequences.

```
df[~(df.Condition.diff() == 0)]

    Condition   Word
0       1       neut
1       2       pos
2       3       neg
5       2       pos
6       1       neut
7       2       pos
```